# Talend Populating Web Service Parameter that is an Array of Strings

Tags: web-services, talend

I am using the tESBConsumer component (using Talend Data Integration 6.4.1) to talk to a SOAP Web Service. We need to use a Web Service method that requires one of its parameters to be an array of strings, such that the payload needs to become something like:

> "...   <simpleParam>Simple Param Value</simpleParam>**<arrayOfStringsParam>
>   <string>Array
>   Item 1</string><string>Array Item
>   2</string><string>Array Item
>   3</string></arrayOfStringsParam>** ..."

I cannot determine how to pass the array into the control to get it in the correct format. There is no type for Schema fields of String[].

I tried a type List but it got written out in the payload as something like:

> "... <arrayOfStringsParam>[Array Item 1, Array Item 2,Array Item
>   3]</arrayOfStringsParam> ..."

.

I tried a type of String and formatted the data in previous steps as

> "<string>Array Item 1</string><string>Array Item
>   2</string><string>Array Item 3</string>"

but in the resulting payload the less-than (<) signs got encoded to "&lt;" so they weren't recognised as proper tags.

Can someone please let me know how to get this data in the appropriate format.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your string array of fixed size ? Do you know how many items will there be in the array ?

Comment: Yes it will be a fixed size for any given Job.

Comment: Since your params array is of fixed size, maybe you can define it in your payload xml schema

Comment: Although the array is of fixed size, the data will vary from input record to input record. If I understand what you are suggesting properly, the data would have to be fixed - is that right?

Comment: No actually I meant define the structure in your payload xml, and map the data from your records to the corresponding xml tag. For instance, if your array always contains 3 strings, you can have 3 tags under <arrayOfStringsParam> and map each one of them.

Comment: I don't actually get to build the XML myself, the Talend Control is taking care of that. The problem is that I am very new to Talend!